# search by datagrid,combobox,datetimepicker

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, datagrid, datetimepicker

I want to do a search by **combobox** and **datimepicker**, I have a table which contains 3 dates: reception, forecast, send and other data and i want then **my combobox contains the previous titles (3 dates)** when I select one of them and I choose date by datetimepicker the result of each date selected  will be show in datagrid

Comment: Is your data already in a datatable/is the datagridview bound to the table?

Comment: yes it is  ,all my data  in dataghridview exist in my database

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, sorry - a [datatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netcore-3.1) is not a database

Comment: sorry I got confused between datatable and database and i have my data in datatable (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your data is in a datatable. If you haven't already done so, a nice easy way to show it in a datagridview is via binding and our life can get easier if we use a bindingsource:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
someDataAdapter.Fill(dt);       //datatable is now full of data

dataGridViewX.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dt }; //bind througha  bindingsource
```

BindingSource supports filtering when the underlying datasource (a datatable, actually via a DataView exposed by the table) does.

This means we can have a combo box SelectedIndexChanged event handler like:

```
somecombo_SelectedIndexChanged(...){

  var bs = dataGridViewX.DataSource as BindingSource;
  var itm = "forecast"; //i presume it comes from somecombo.SelectedItem etc

  bs.Filter = $"[{itm}] = #{datepicker.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}#";

}
```

I assume your combo contains the names of the columns in the table. If not you'll have to decode them from whatever they show, to whatever the column name is, then we set up a filter like:

```
"[forecast] = #2020-09-21#"
```

For all records with the date of 21st Sep. Note that dates can have a time portion too, so if your dates have times you'll need more like:

```
 bs.Filter = $"[{itm}] >= #{datepicker.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}# AND [{itm}] < #{datepicker.Value.AddDays(1):yyyy-MM-dd}# ";
```

A date with a time is like a number with a decimal: 1.234 wouldn't be matched by "equals 1", but it would be matched by "greater or equal 1 and less than 2"

---

Likewise have an event handler on the dtp that changes the filter when the dtp value changes